# How to check if field is null or empty in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to check if a field is `NULL` or *empty*. I have this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(field1, 'empty') as field1 from tablename
```

I need to add an additional check `field1 != ""` something like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(field1, 'empty') OR field1 != ""  as field1 from tablename
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Either use

```
SELECT IF(field1 IS NULL or field1 = '', 'empty', field1) as field1 
from tablename
```

or use the following code, which I copied from another answer (by [Himanshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/himanshu)) to this same question, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17833019/441757 —

> ```
> SELECT case when field1 IS NULL or field1 = ''
>             then 'empty'
>             else field1
>        end as field1  from tablename
> ```

If you only want to check for `null` and not for empty strings then you can also use `ifnull()` or `coalesce(field1, 'empty')`. But that is not suitable for empty strings.

Comment: Note that if you want also to consider the strings as empty those with only spaces, you could use the TRIM function like `SELECT IF(field1 IS NULL or TRIM(field1) = '', 'empty', field1) as field1 FROM tablename`.

Comment: You should not add an alternative way when it is already given in other answers.

Answer (score 46):

Using `nullif` does the trick:

```
SELECT ifnull(nullif(field1,''),'empty or null') AS field1
  FROM tablename;
```

How it works: `nullif` is returning `NULL` if `field` is an empty string, otherwise returns the field itself. This has both the cases covered (the case when field is NULL and the case when it's an empty string).

Comment: nullif(field, '') is usefull

Comment: This is very useful, but to be more clear, the second argument of ifnull() in the example should be 'empty or null'.

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively you can also use `CASE` for the same:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL OR field1 = '' 
       THEN 'empty' 
       ELSE field1 END AS field1
FROM tablename.
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [the `IFNULL` function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp) inside the `IF`. This will be a little shorter, and there will be fewer repetitions of the field name.

```
SELECT IF(IFNULL(field1, '') = '', 'empty', field1) AS field1 
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create a function to make this easy.

```
create function IFEMPTY(s text, defaultValue text)
returns text deterministic
return if(s is null or s = '', defaultValue, s);
```

Using:

```
SELECT IFEMPTY(field1, 'empty') as field1 
from tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

By trimming and comparing, we ensure we also take care of empty or tab or space character content in the field.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(col_1))='' or col_1 IS NULL THEN 'Not available'
        ELSE col_1
    END AS col_alias
FROM
    my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT  2 AS RTYPE,V.ID AS VTYPE, DATE_FORMAT(ENTDT, ''%d-%m-%Y'')  AS ENTDT,V.NAME AS VOUCHERTYPE,VOUCHERNO,ROUND(IF((DR_CR)>0,(DR_CR),0),0) AS DR ,ROUND(IF((DR_CR)<0,(DR_CR)*-1,0),2) AS CR ,ROUND((dr_cr),2) AS BALAMT, IF(d.narr IS NULL OR d.narr='''',t.narration,d.narr) AS NARRATION 
    FROM trans_m AS t JOIN trans_dtl AS d ON(t.ID=d.TRANSID)
    JOIN acc_head L ON(D.ACC_ID=L.ID) 
    JOIN VOUCHERTYPE_M AS V ON(T.VOUCHERTYPE=V.ID)  
    WHERE T.CMPID=',COMPANYID,' AND  d.ACC_ID=',LEDGERID ,' AND t.entdt>=''',FROMDATE ,''' AND t.entdt<=''',TODATE ,''' ',VTYPE,'
    ORDER BY CAST(ENTDT AS DATE)) AS ta
```

Comment: here anybody can find there qry's solution.its a runing qry and hope it will b usefull for everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(TRIM(COALESCE(field1, '')) = '', '[ empty ]', field1) FROM tablename
```

field1 is null or any length of whitespace

See [TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) and [IS NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) for more info.

Also [Working with null](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html) values from the MySQL docs

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to check in PHP , then you should do something like :

```
$query_s =mysql_query("SELECT YOURROWNAME from `YOURTABLENAME` where name = $name");
$ertom=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);
if ('' !== $ertom['YOURROWNAME']) {
  //do your action
  echo "It was filled";
} else { 
  echo "it was empty!";
}
```

Comment: `$isnull = (empty($ertom['YOUROWNAME']) ? empty : not empty);`

That's a little shorter..