# how to avoid empty strings in mysql without using check constraint?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE emp3(
   id int(3) auto_increment,
   first_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   last_name varchar(30), 
   email varchar(20) not null unique,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

`ALTER TABLE emp3
ADD CONSTRAINT check_name_not_blank CHECK ((first_name<>'')),
ADD CONSTRAINT check_email_not_blank CHECK ((email<>''))`

check constraint is not working in `mysql`.so how can i use this condition in a `stored procedure` so as to avoid empty strings?

Comment: You can use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Easy enough to google - try this for starters http://mysqlserverteam.com/new-and-old-ways-to-emulate-check-constraints-domain/

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832906/how-to-check-if-field-is-null-or-empty-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if field is null or empty mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832906/how-to-check-if-field-is-null-or-empty-mysql)