# MySQL how to concatenate middle, first, and last name while handling empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have a MySQL table like this:

```
middle   first    last       name
---------------------------  -------------
         reyes    sanchez    reyes sanchez
         antonio  cruz       antonio cruz
m        michael  middleton  m michael middleton
a        greg     allen      a greg allen
```

How can I write a statement to combine these 3 columns where it looks like the column called `name`? We can assume that middle, first, and last columns are not nullable but can be empty, have empty spaces, or have spaces on the left/right side if nonempty?

I tried to write something like this:

```
CONCAT(middle + ' ', RTRIM(first), RTRIM(last)) AS name
```

But even the first result showed this: `0reyessanchez` and I am not sure how to insert a space between and I have no idea why MySQL is inserting a 0 instead of taking the blank.

Comment: `middle + ' '` is a mathematical expression. You probably mean `CONCAT(middle, ' ')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if field is null or empty in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832906/how-to-check-if-field-is-null-or-empty-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> select middle, first, last from mytable;
+--------+---------+-----------+
| middle | first   | last      |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|        | reyes   | sanchez   |
|        | antonio | cruz      |
| m      | michael | middleton |
| a      | greg    | allen     |
+--------+---------+-----------+

mysql> select concat_ws(' ', 
     nullif(trim(middle), ''), 
     nullif(trim(first), ''), 
     nullif(trim(last), '')) 
    as fullname 
  from mytable;
+---------------------+
| s                   |
+---------------------+
| reyes sanchez       |
| antonio cruz        |
| m michael middleton |
| a greg allen        |
+---------------------+
```

MySQL's [CONCAT_WS() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) ignores NULLs.

Comment: nice use of nullif.  but it's needed for first and last too

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the value you want:

`TRIM( REGEXP_REPLACE( CONCAT(middle, ' ', first, ' ', last), '[[:space:]]+', ' ') )`

Explanation:

`CONCAT(middle, ' ', first, ' ', last)` concatenates the three strings.

`PREG_REPLACE()` replaces multiple spaces with a single space (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52855455/378779).

And finally `TRIM()` trims any leading any trailing spaces.

Comment: this gets rid of double (or more) spaces inside of the name parts, which may or may not be a good thing

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly check if a column is non-blank before adding a space after it:

```
rtrim(
    concat(
        if(length(trim(middle)),concat(trim(middle),' '),''),
        if(length(trim(first)),concat(trim(first),' '),''),
        ltrim(last)
    )
)
```

Comment: what happens if it is blank then in this sql code?

Comment: if it is blank it is doesn't get added (for middle and first) or gets added but to no effect (for last)